# How can I access this list and also be thread safe?

Tags: java, multithreading, list, collections

My main spawns 2 threads and they both need to access the same list. I am not sure what the best way to do this is. Here is what I have, but I still run into concurrentModificationException.

```
class Parent {
   private List<String> data;

   public List<String> getData() {
      return data;
   }

   public static void main(String args[]) {
      Parent p = new Parent();
      p.start();
   }

   public void start() {
      Thread a = new Thread(new A(this)).start();
      Thread b = new Thread(new B(this)).start();
   }

   public A implements Runnable {
      private Parent parent;

      public A(Parent p) {
         parent = p;
      }

      public void run() {
         while (true) {
            parent.getData().add("data");
         }
      }
   }

   public B implements Runnable {
      private Parent parent;

      public B(Parent p) {
         parent = p;
      }

      public void run() {
         Iterator<String> i = parent.getData().iterator();
         while(i.hasNext()) {
            // do more stuff with i
            i.remove();
         }
      }
   } 
}
```

my `A` class is basically a producer of data and `B` is the consumer. I accept the possibility that I am going about this the wrong way. So all help is welcome. I just need to safely be able to add to a list from one thread and remove an item from the list from another thread. thanks in advance.

Comment: Don't use a list in place of a queue. There are plenty of utilities meant for producer/consumer operations in the [java.util.concurrent](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/package-summary.html) package.

Comment: You probably want a BlockingQueue, not a List.

Comment: cool ill look into those. if i swap out the list should the rest of it theoretically be ok?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, for a producer/consumer, I'd recommend [LinkedBlockingQueue](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/LinkedBlockingQueue.html) or [ConcurrentLinkedQueue](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentLinkedQueue.html). This will handle concurrent reads and writes (or pushes/polls in this case).

You'll probably want your consumer to run until some shutdown condition is sent to it. If you were using a blocking queue, this means you will want to send a queued item that indicates that the consumer should stop consuming. This would be a blocking queue implementation with a shutdown.

```
   public enum QueueItemType {
      CONSUMABLE,
      SHUTDOWN
   }

   public class QueueItem {
      public final QueueItemType type;
      public final String payload;

      public QueueItem(QueueItemType type, String payload) {
         this.type = type;
         this.payload = payload;
      }
   }

   public class B implements Runnable {
      private Parent parent;

      public B(Parent p) {
         parent = p;
      }

      public void run() {
         while(true) {
            QueueItem data = parent.getData().poll();
            if (data.type == QueueItemType.SHUTDOWN) {
               break;
            } else {
               // do more stuff with data.payload
            }
         }
      }
   }
```

Note that there is no null check for a blocking queue's `poll` result. This is because, by definition, blocking queues block the running thread until something is there.

If you prefer to have a consumer that does not contend with the producer, then you will need to poll periodically and sleep the consumer thread. Here's an example if you used the ConcurrentLinkedQueue:

```
   public class B implements Runnable {
      private Parent parent;

      public B(Parent p) {
         parent = p;
      }

      public void run() {
         while(parent.isStillRunning()) {
            String data = parent.getData().poll();
            if (data != null) {
              // do more stuff with data
            } else {
              Thread.sleep(10 /*10 ms, but you can make this whatever poll interval you want*/);
            }
         }
      }
   }
```

Comment: Don't use Thread.sleep() for this. Instead shut down the queue by setting a volatile flag and interrupting the consumer thread, or by putting a "poison pill" in the queue. Otherwise, great answer.

Comment: Feel free to improve the answer :). The "poison pill" approach would definitely work well with a blocking queue. The advantage to a ConcurrentLinkedQueue is that it has no contention between the producer and the consumer, which is a really cool property of the underlying algorithm. So the thread polling might take some CPU, but the producer will never get locked out by the consumer.

Comment: I am going to look into this "poison pill", I need to avoid sleeping as much as possible

Comment: I've updated the first example to use a poison pill.

Comment: ok I like this, it is simple and better than what I was thinking before. Thx for the help @Chill

Answer (score 0):

The least impactful change, could be to use a setter that is synchronized.
That way a thread would have to wait on the lock to be released before being able to add to the Collection.